# SQL for xml construction issues

Tags: sql, xml

I have a issue with my FOR XML clause in SQL. The table with the data in has interval as a colum (see example below), in the data output as of now i get the same date for every interval i got in the columns.

SQL Table:

```
ID  CTID    dDate   dtmInterval CO_Forecast AHT_Forecast
1   2   2015-10-13  08:00:00    5.05004 457.67751
2   2   2015-10-13  08:15:00    5.24004 457.67751
3   2   2015-10-13  08:30:00    4.49004 457.67751
4   2   2015-10-13  08:45:00    4.50004 457.67751
5   2   2015-10-13  09:00:00    5.65004 457.67751
```

I use this code in my FOR XML clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1000

 [ctID]
,[forecastData/date/day] = Day(dDate) 
,[forecastData/date/month] = month(dDate)
,[forecastData/date/year] = year(dDate)
,[co_forecast] AS [forecastData/dailyData/contactsReceived]
,[AHT_Forecast] AS [forecastData/dailyData/averageAHT]

FROM [ProductionForecast].[dbo].[Forecast]

group by [co_forecast], [AHT_Forecast], [CTID], dDate

FOR XML PATH ('ctForecast'), ROOT ('forecastImport')
```

The output i get is following:

```
<forecastImport>
  <ctForecast>
    <ctID>2</ctID>
    <forecastData>
      <date>
        <day>13</day>
        <month>10</month>
        <year>2015</year>
      </date>
      <dailyData>
        <contactsReceived>5.05004</contactsReceived>
        <averageAHT>457.67751</averageAHT>
      </dailyData>
    </forecastData>
  </ctForecast>
  <ctForecast>
    <ctID>2</ctID>
    <forecastData>
      <date>
        <day>13</day>
        <month>10</month>
        <year>2015</year>
      </date>
      <dailyData>
        <contactsReceived>5.24004</contactsReceived>
        <averageAHT>457.67751</averageAHT>
      </dailyData>
    </forecastData>
  </ctForecast>
```

Everything clamp is opening and closing the correct places, but i get the same date 96 times in a row which the server who needs this data cant read.

What i want it to output is following:

```
<forecastImport>
<ctForecast>
<ctID>95</ctID>
<forecastData>
<date><day>01</day><month>11</month><year>2015</year></date>
<dailyData>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
<averageAHT>0</averageAHT>
</dailyData>
</forecastData>
</ctForecast>
<ctForecast>
<ctID>95</ctID>
<forecastData>
<date><day>02</day><month>11</month><year>2015</year></date>
<dailyData>
<contactsReceived>594.81653</contactsReceived>
<averageAHT>387</averageAHT>
</dailyData>
</forecastData>
</ctForecast>
```

I have tried alot of different things and right now i only see one answer which is to get a stored procedure up and running which will transfer the data to a new table without the dtminterval column, but i would like to use what i already have available, is it possible ?

kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it is this code to be used:

```
SELECT
 [CTID]
,[dDate]
,[CO_Forecast] = Sum([CO_Forecast])
,AHT_Forecast = CASE WHEN Sum([CO_Forecast]) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(LOAD) /         Sum([CO_Forecast]) 
END

FROM
(
SELECT
[ID]
,[CTID]
,[dDate]
,[dtmInterval]
,[CO_Forecast]
,[AHT_Forecast]
,LOAD = CO_Forecast * AHT_Forecast

FROM            
[ProductionForecast].[dbo].[Forecast]) AS Sub

GROUP BY 
 [CTID]
,[dDate]
```

Comment: Great that you found the answer yourself (upvoted this...). Now you should mark your own answer as accepted, to show this question being closed... Thx